# How do I compile a file whose name begins with “-” (hyphen a.k.a. dash or minus)?

Tags: gcc, clang, command-line-interface

I have a file called `-.o` that was created with:

```
echo "int main(){}" | cc -xc -c -
```

**How do I link this file to a binary ?**

The command is the same as :

```
echo "int main(){}" | cc -xc -c - -o-.o
```

Where `cc` is the default compiler (tested with `gcc 4.8.4` and `clang 800.0.42.1`), `-xc` considers input to be written in C language, `-c` generates object file, `-` takes stdin as input file and `-o-.o` specifies the name of the output file.

All of these commands fail :

```
cc -.o
cc -- -.o
cc "-.o"
cc \-.o
cc \\-.o
cc "\-.o"
```

With errors like this :

```
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--’
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-.o’
cc: error: \-.o: No such file or directory
```

Obviously I could rename the file but this is not the point here. I wonder why the `--` is not implemented as in ls, cp, mv, ...

Comment: @Destructor I'm not giving a strange file name. The compiler does.

Comment: Hmm, how about `cc ./-.o`?

Comment: In the same vein as `cc ./-.o` you could also try `cc ../parent-dir/-.o` as outlined in http://superuser.com/questions/120078/unix-files-starting-with-a-dash

Comment: "The compiler does" - It does with your allowance. It is you who allow this name when you compile the source code of that object file. Specify a reasonable name with `-o` option.

Comment: Oh @aschepler you're a genius. How didn't I think about it before. You can post this as an answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Matthias Why though?

Comment: @KonradRudolph The question was answered before on superuser, therefore, Bilow could have found an answer by trying to search for his problem. Having another question for the same issue provokes that discussions in either question are missing from the other, which is bad. Apart from that, ./-.o is one of many options, all of which navigate to the file from a directory, e.g. absolute path (/...), relative to local (./...), relative to parent (../...).

Comment: @Matthias I meant, “why [the heck] would you use `../parent-dir/-.o` instead of simply `./-.o`?” It makes *no* sense.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I understood what you meant. I have given you the reasons for me to write that comment. I will state them again: The question was asked and answered before and instead of having information spread across all occurrences, it should be discussed in a single place. Moreover, the only answer here does not explain why the proposed solution works (navigate to file via directory), and it could be discussed in more detail. Besides, the discussion here does not talk about double dash (--) and links.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The question should have been closed in the first place IMHO.

Comment: @Matthias I still don’t understand why you’re (also) providing a solution that makes absolutely no sense and is inferior in every way to another solution (that was already posted). This has nothing whatsoever to do with whether the question had already been posted before. — Apart from that I disagree that the question should have been closed. It’s a valid question without an existing duplicate on this site (at least nobody linked to a duplicate).

Comment: Hi @Matthias,
I'm afraid I don't agree with you because the accepted answer on superuser does not solve my problem. The question is not the same. Compilers do **not** accept `--`. Also you are suggesting I didn't search for my problem but guess what, I did and I really had a hard time two years ago. Apart from that, I agree duplicates should not exist but it don't think it is one here.
Thanks anyway for contributing.

Comment: I think we have a different understanding w.r.t. what is duplicate information and what is beneficial knowledge. This question is very specific, the one I was referring to is general. I do not need to discuss this with you, and I certainly do not need to change your opinion. I hope the information is helpful for future people experiencing this problem. Have a great year!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
cc ./-.o
```

(from a comment by [@aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640/aschepler))